# Check if couple of ranges are met in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below, I would like to check if group of named ranges are met in worksheet and if yes do something, but I receive error when range is not met in if line, how to solve it? thanks

```
If Range("Range1") Is Nothing Or Range("Range2") Is Nothing Or Range("Range3") Is Nothing Or Range("Range4") Is Nothing Or Range("Range5") Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "Check if in file each of required range is mentioned!"
Else
'do something
End if
```

Comment: What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: Run-time error '1004'

Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: Are all your ranges defined? you refer to `"Range1","Range2"` etc, but are those named ranges defined? If you didn't set those named ranges `Excel` will throw an error.

Comment: One of them could be not defined and I want to check if it is defined

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to check if the `.Name` matches with the named `Range` you defined and using an `Integer` counter to match if the amount of `Ranges` are found.

see code below:

```
Private Sub CheckNamedRanges()

    Dim nm As Name
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each nm In wb.Names
        If nm.Name = "Range1" Or nm.Name = "Range2" Or nm.Name = "Range3" Or nm.Name = "Range4" Or nm.Name = "Range5" Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    If i = 5 Then
        'do something
    Else
        MsgBox "Check if in file each of required range is mentioned!"
    End If
End Sub
```

*(Due note I am not 100% sure this is the most efficient way)*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Sub CheckTheRange()
Dim CheckMyRange As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set CheckMyRange = Range("MyRange")
On Error GoTo 0
If CheckMyRange Is Nothing Then
     'Error, range not found
Else
     'Go for it
End If

End Sub
```